# Does laravel database seeding have a limit?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, faker

I have a program that in total will insert approx 500000 database entries in a year. I am trying to test it to make sure that everything works correctly if I have 2 years worth of data? When I run my database seeder though, it just cancels out when it hits that seeder.

This brings up the question, is there a maximum number of entries that you can store in a MySQL database when using laravels seeders and faker library? Because this seeder does work with a smaller number of entries e.g. 1000.

looking at data from the faker library it seems like it doesnt specify this. also looking through the docs there is no mention of size limits.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/seeding

https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker

Comment: php may be timing out .. You may want to look into your ini file and increase (temporarily) that timout time to see if that might be your issue .. Also what do your web server logs say?

Comment: @Zak I thought that execution is unlimited via CLI?

Comment: `max_timout` isn't the same as `max_execution_time`  --  `max_execution_time` applies to the CLI ..

Comment: @Zak I just went into my max_execution_time and changed it to 3600 but it still times out after like 5 seconds.

Comment: There's a package I've used called `orangehill/iseed` (https://github.com/orangehill/iseed), which has the following at the bottom: *"Please note that some users encountered a problem with large DB table exports (error when seeding from table with many records). The issue was solved by splitting input data into smaller chunks of elements per insert statement."* You might be experiencing something similar; can you chop your insert statements up?

Comment: @TimLewis It looks like the max laravel lets me do is around 50000 entries per seed, I would imagine it is due to a memory capacity.

Comment: Have you checked your error logs to see if there's a specific error being thrown?

Comment: @AkenRoberts Just looked over my logs and no errors

Comment: I found that 40,000 rows was the maximum the seeder would let me perform at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a real thing that Mysql have a limitation called "TimeOut".

In mysql there is many variables like `delayed insert limit`, `timeout`, `query cache limit` and Other that Overall are limitation for many query specialy insert in a part of time.

For example look at this [Mysql Server System Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_delayed_insert_limit)